# Relating a bug id to its date of creation ubuntu

Tags: python, launchpadlib

I am writing a python script to pick up bugs of ubuntu using the lauchpadlib.
I want to know all the bugs reported between a certain time period.
Now there are a few question that I have in mind.
Are the id's of the bugs incremented serially in ubuntu launchpad?
Ans how can I figure out the id that I need to begin with?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bugs on Launchpad are incremented serially.

You can get the date that a bug was created like so:

```
>>> import os
>>> from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
>>> 
>>> cachedir = os.path.expanduser("~/.launchpadlib/cache/")
>>> launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('find_branches',
...                                         'production',
...                                         cachedir)
>>> bug = launchpad.bugs['1214615']
>>> bug.date_created
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 20, 21, 38, 24, 839934, tzinfo=TimeZone(0))
```